# Android TextWatcher decimal numbers

Tags: android, regex

I'm trying to create regular expression, that will find only something like that:
**1 ; 12 ; 12,4 ; 12,45 ; 12.4 ; 12.45 (numbers can be different ofc)**.

That's my regex regex: *^[0-9]?[0-9]?[,.]?[0-9]?[0-9]?$*, 
but it passes e.g. **1234**, but I don't want this.

I want to create EditText with TextWatcher, which will filtrate text by regex.

My code:

```
TextWatcher DiscountTextWatcher = new TextWatcher()
{
    private final Pattern sPattern = Pattern.compile("^[0-9]?[0-9]?[,.]?[0-9]?[0-9]?$");

        private CharSequence mText = "";

        private boolean isValid(CharSequence s) {
            return sPattern.matcher(s).matches();
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                      int after){
            mText = isValid(s) ? s : mText;
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
        {
            if (!isValid(s) || s.length() > 4)
            {
                addDocumentDiscountValue.removeTextChangedListener(this);
                addDocumentDiscountValue.setText(mText);
                addDocumentDiscountValue.setSelection(mText.length());
                addDocumentDiscountValue.addTextChangedListener(this);
            }
        }
    };
```

**EDIT:**

Now I've got better regex (Thanks to @nu11p01n73R) but it still doesn't work. I **can't write colon after two numbers**, dunno why. That's strange, but **three numbers in a row works**...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem with the regex**

The mistake you made was you made every character class optional.

So the regex engine will try to fool by eliminating those classes which it doesn't need to match

That is when you give the input

```
1234
```

the regex engine would safely ignore the character clas `[,.]` so that it can match the input, because you gave them as optional.

**How `^[0-9]?[0-9]?[,.]?[0-9]?[0-9]?$` matches `1234`**

```
1234
|
[0-9]? #first optional

1234
 |
[0-9]? #second optional

1234
  |
  Here the next patern is [,.]. The regex engine cannot match this pattern to input. Since it is optional, it just forgets for the moment that such a pettern was there ;)

1234
  |
 [0-9]? # Third optional

1234
   |
 [0-9]? #Frourth optional

1234
    |
    $ End of input. Successfull match
```

**Solution**

```
/^[0-9]{1,2}([.,][0-9]{1,2})?$/
```

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/jE4kX7/1)

Comment: That was so easy! Thank you sir.

Comment: Incorrect if you want to avoid double zeros such as `00.23`

Comment: `^(0|[1-9][0-9]{0,1})([.,][0-9]{1,2})?$` would work as a replacement

Comment: @EdGeorge I agree to that. But op has to mentioned on those strict validation rules. Anyways if he/she wants such strict rules, then the pattern  you provided would do fine

Comment: @nu11p01n73R Yep, also +1 as your answer is extremely clear and links to an excellent demo

Comment: @nu11p01n73R Regex is excellent, but it still doesn't work, I can write 3 numbers in a row, well...

Comment: @KurdTt- Sorry I didn't get you. What do  you mean by 3 numbers in a row. please provide a sample input. Do look at this link https://regex101.com/r/jE4kX7/2 Here each line corresponds to different inputs that are being expected

Comment: @nu11p01n73R I can't restore old value from mText variable. For example, when I write "123", regex value is false, but It doesn't back him to "12", but I try to fix it, anyway thanks!

Comment: @KurdTt- The regex part is good to go ( It gives the expected output, say for `123` it is `False` ) For the change in mText am not sure of the logic that you are using